# How do I fill in a W-8BEN for for sites such as Zazzle as an individual?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, non-resident, form-w-8-ben

I have have some cash sitting (and growing) in a Zazzle.com account for a while.  In order to have this cash paid to me as a U.K. citizen still living in the U.K., I need to submit a [W-8BEN](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw8ben.pdf) form.  I have tried this 5 times now and gotten to the stage where most of it is accepted.
The problem is that Zazzle give zero to little feedback on what is wrong with it.

I am now at the point where there is something wrong with Part II, Section 10.  I have answered that I am entitled to a 0% tax rate as per [Article 12, paragraph 1](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/uk.pdf).  the type of income I have declared is

> Royalties (from items sold bearing my designs)

and the "*additional conditions in the article and paragraph*" being:

> Royalties derived and beneficially owned by a resident of the United
>   Kingdom shall be exempt from tax by the United States.

But the response from Zazzle, was a cryptic

> Your form is nearly good enough to be accepted. However, there are a
>   few things that still need to be looked at. The last part in section
>   10 needs to be adjusted.   What you currently have doesn’t contain the
>   information needed to provide you the benefit. It would help to keep
>   in mind the type of income you receive from Zazzle. It may also help
>   to refer to the type of work you provide to the Zazzle website.  This
>   link may help you to clarify your wording (refer to sub section
>   “Royalties” in the link below):
>   https://www.irs.gov/publications/p525/ar02.html#en_US_2015_publink1000229288

What are they expecting that I am not doing or not doing properly?

UPDATE:

After my latest attempt, the response -regarding my entry `Royalties (from items sold bearing my designs)`- was a very unhelpful:

> What you have written in brackets next to your type of income in Part
>   II section 10 is similar to what we are looking for the last part of
>   section 10 but the wording is not exactly what we are looking for.
>   Please keep that in mind as well as the type of work you submit to the
>   products on the Zazzle website and your type of income and search the
>   subsection "Royalties" below:
>
> https://www.irs.gov/publications/p525/ar02.html#en_US_2015_publink1000229288

Comment: My suspicion is that they need you to classify it according to one of those specific sub-categories listed on the link they provided, so I would write "Royalties from copyrights on my artistic work". I also suspect (based on similar interactions with UK entities) that they aren't allowed to tell you "write these words directly: XXXXX", so they are being as helpful as they can.

Comment: Try "Royalties from copyrights on … artistic works"

Comment: An alternative to paying their fees (at least in the US) is to list a new item.  Apparently that gives you another year or something before the fees kick in.  You might be able to take an existing design and move it to a different item; not sure of the restrictions.

Comment: I have plenty of ideas for new items but I've not added them because the money is just building up and I can't get to it.

Comment: @Vicky does that mean that only one entry needs to change?

Comment: I have no idea, you haven’t provided us enough information to be able to answer that. If it’s effectively free to keep making attempts to submit the form then why not give it a go and see if it gets through?

Comment: @Vicky it's actually all the information there is, the rest is just personal details really and as you can see, it's this one section they are telling me is wrong.  I'll give it a go though, thanks.  If you're right I suggest you add an answer so you can reep the bounty ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the end was in Part II, Section 10, the phrase

> Royalties on copyrights on my artistic works

in both "*type of income*" and "*additional conditions in the article and paragraph*" entries

Comment: Thank you, I have been going back and forth with them in email with piecemeal corrections and additions to the form.

Now, found on their when page it doesn't let you enter COUNTY in the address, so it doesn't match the one on the form.